# What is the best practice for tracking a single global variable in MEAN Stack?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I have a global array that I need to track. I don't want to just create a global variable that will be lost if the server gets reset.

It seems inefficient to create a new table just for a single variable, but is that the only way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the array to be stored permanently in a way that persists even after server reboots - aside from using the database approach, you could try this:

**Write your array into a JSON file:**

```
const fs = require('fs');

let arrayData = {
    array: ["Where", "are", "you", "BB-8?"]
};

let data = JSON.stringify(arrayData);

fs.writeFile('data.json', data, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Save successful!');
});
```

You can then read this JSON file at any time and include it inside a module for tracking usage.

There is also this module called [node-persist](https://github.com/simonlast/node-persist), but I haven't tried it before.

Comment: Seems a little hacky, but it'll work. +1 for the Star Wars reference.

Comment: :) Could you please upvote and mark this as a selected answer if it helped you?